# app engine dynamically run code in a backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Currently a user initiate an action, then a task is being queued and my code is being executed.

I want to allow the option to use a backend instead of a task.

What would be the best approach?

If I set one backend named "ExtraPower" to be dynamic with 1 instance, then... what? What should I do to activate it (with certain parameters)? Which URL should I call excatly?

Alternatively I read I can use the Pull queue, which is fine, but then again, how do I tell that backend to go and lease a task to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enqueue a regular (push queue) task against a backend. How to do that is described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Push_Queues_and_Backends).

Comment: Great, didn't notice that, maybe because I look at the Java docs.. anyway, once again Mr. Johnson - thank you!!

Comment: Pardon me Nick, but, just a quick question: Does a backend's URL always must be /_ah/start or?... it seems like the only hole I have about this issue.. (didn't throughly check yet though).

Comment: @Poni Backends have their own subdomain. `/_ah/start` is just the reserved URL for the startup handler. You can enqueue a task against any URL on your backend.